# Understandng a mixture of Rails and Bootstrap code

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
- if signed_in?
  = primary_nav(                                                                                                              |
    title: { text: t('.home_page'), href: root_path },                                                                |
    links: [                                                                                                                  |
      { active: request.path.starts_with?('/performance/'), text: t('.performance'), href: performance_my_path },   |
    ]                                                                                                                         |
  ) do
```

I am trying to undersntad this code, this is in Rails and this is in `application.html.haml`
**My main confusion** is where we have those keywords like **title, links, active, text**
What language is it? It isn't Rails? is it ? Or is it Twitter Bootstrap?
So If I want to add another link on the same level as performance, I should just add another hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`primary_nav` is a method defined somewhere in your application, probably in some helper.
This method takes a hash as an argument, and 'title' and 'links' are keys of this hash.
You should find a definition of `primary_nav` in your application.
It isn't related to twitter-bootstrap in any way.